# comma-separated string to array

Tags: php

I'm looking for the simplest way to take a single variable such as:

```
$variable = 'left,middle,right';
```

and write it to an `array();` split at the commas.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',', $variable);
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you string gets a little bit more complex (i.e. elements can be in quotes and both the delimiter and the quoting character can appear within an element) you might also be interested in [fgetcsv()](http://docs.php.net/fgetcsv) and [str_getcsv()](http://docs.php.net/str_getcsv)

```
$variable = '"left,right","middle", "up,down"';
$row = str_getcsv($variable);
var_dump($row);
```

prints

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "left,right"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "middle"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "up,down"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `preg_split()`

```
$variable = 'left  ,  middle,   right';
print_r ( preg_split("/\s*,\s*/",$variable));
```