# Remove a string php

Tags: php

I have this value: `samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f`
Best approach to remove all the string from the beginning of the word until the `|`. The `|` is the key here , on where to end. The output should be `d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f`.

Comment: is there only one `|` character in the string?

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comma-separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322505/comma-separated-string-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
substr( strstr('samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f', '|'), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode`

```
explode("|","samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f")[1];
```

check this : https://eval.in/591968

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`stristr()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

```
$str="samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f";
echo ltrim(stristr($str, '|'),"|");
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short solution using `substr` and `strpos` functions:

```
$str = "samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f";
$result = substr($str, strpos($str, "|") + 1); // contains "d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f"
```

Answer (score 2):

Split your string by using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Then return the last element of the array using [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
 end(explode('|', 'samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f'));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use php explode($delimiter,$yourstring) function

```
$str="samplemail@yahoo.com|d76c3c301eb754c62b981f7208158a9f";
$exploded_str_array=explode('|', $str);
echo $required_str=$exploded_str_array[1];
```

//this contains the second part of the string delimited by |
[php manual for the explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)