# make an Array from 2 Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this:

```
$Array1 = "FirstName, LastName, Email";
$Array2 = "John, Doe, johndoe@email.com";
```

Using a foreach or other means, Could the final array format to look like this?

```
$mergedArrays = array(
    'FirstName'        =>"John",
    'LastName'     => "Doe",
    'Email'       =>'johndoe@email.com',
);

print_r($mergedArrays);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: `print_r(array_combine(explode(', ',$Array1),explode(', ',$Array2)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that both array will contain the same number separeted by comma, use this:

Version 1 (testing with 100000 takes ~0.08s, +-4x faster)

```
<?php
$Array1 = "FirstName, LastName, Email";
$Array2 = "John, Doe, johndoe@email.com";

$Array1 = explode(',', preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/',',',$Array1)); //remove spaces before and after comma
$Array2 = explode(',', preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/',',',$Array2));

if(count($Array1) == count($Array2)) {
    $result = array_combine($Array1, $Array2);
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [FirstName] => John
    [LastName] => Doe
    [Email] => johndoe@email.com
)
```

Alternative version from @castis (testing with 100000 takes ~0.3s)

```
$Array1 = explode(',',$Array1);
$Array2 = explode(',',$Array2);

$result = array_combine(array_map('trim', $Array1), array_map('trim', $Array2));
```

Comment: One small improve  `explode(', ',$Array1)`;

Comment: Updated with regex to remove before and after extra space.

Comment: would be less confusing to `array_combine(array_map(trim, $Array1), array_map(trim, $Array2));` but +1 overall

Comment: Updated. The regex code runs faster. Of course, with 3 records makes no difference, but just for curiosity.

Comment: _"The regex code runs faster"_ - You don't happen to have the source for those test results? Not saying your test is wrong, I'm just curious. Or they are easy enough to do myself :-)

Comment: I'd created a string with 100000 elements, runned both codes and measured the time taken. Not a scientifically approach, though.

Comment: Ok. So you hade two strings with 100000 elements in each? Not running those code blocks 100000 times? Well, if we did the later, I guess the array functions would take the bulk of the time.

Comment: Create two strings with 100000 elements in each, then run the code. In other words, replaced the initial values of `$Array1` and `$Array2` with a much bigger string.

Comment: Ah, array_combine, no need for foreach

Comment: Exploding on anything other than comma-space is a poor choice.  Look at all the extra effort you have to go to just to prepare/mop-up the dangling spaces.  Both of the above approaches are heavy-handed for no good/apparent reason.  If you going to go to the trouble to benchmark, compare against smith's commented solution.

Comment: As an aside, if you are going to perform 1. a regex function call to prepare optionally spaced delimiters (not that his question has them) and 2. a subsequent explode call ...then you should only be calling one regex function that can handle variable delimiters.  Know which one?  [ghostdog74 does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2322733/2943403)

Comment: Wow @FelippeDuarte! I really like your clear approach to this question. And definitely, appreciate the if(count) statement!

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a foreach (where array_combine would do):

```
<?php

$fields = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'];
$values = ['John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@email.com'];

foreach($fields as $k => $field)
    $result[$field] = $values[$k];

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'FirstName' => 'John',
    'LastName' => 'Doe',
    'Email' => 'johndoe@email.com',
)
```

Comment: Your input doesn't look like the OP's input.  `$Array1` and `$Array2` would be better labeled `$csv1` and `$csv2`.

Comment: @mickmackusa I made an assumption there that the OP had taken a shortcut when writing down their arrays for the question.

Comment: If the input really starts out as a string it smells like CSV input.  Perhaps `str_getcsv` could help here.

Comment: I would like `str_getcsv()` here if it allowed two-character delimiters.  A bit disappointing that my downvote on the question was neutralized, this undermines my fair action.  (No research, no attempt, bad variable naming impacts question clarity.)